# SQL query MIN value in a range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am collecting min and max pagecount values within an interval (quarterly) from printers stored in a MS SQL db.

```
SELECT 
  p_printerName AS Printer
  , DATEPART(q,  pmh_pollDate) AS Quartal
  , DATEPART(yy, pmh_pollDate) AS Year
  , MIN(pmh_pageCount) AS first
  , MAX(pmh_pageCount) AS last
  , MIN(pmh_pageCountMono) AS first_Mono
  , MAX(pmh_pageCountMono) AS last_Mono
  , MIN(pmh_pageCountColor) AS first_Color
  , MAX(pmh_pageCountColor) AS last_Color
FROM [group] INNER JOIN printerGroup ON g_groupID = pg_groupID 
             INNER JOIN printer ON pg_printerID = p_printerID 
             INNER JOIN printerMeterHistory ON p_printerID = pmh_printerID
WHERE
  (p_printerName LIKE 'WBMP015')   
GROUP BY 
  g_groupName
  , p_printerName
  , DATEPART(yy, pmh_pollDate)
  , DATEPART(q, pmh_pollDate)
```

The table with printer data look something like this (shortened):

```
p_printerName   pmh_pollDate    pmh_pageCount   pmh_pageCountMono   pmh_pageCountColor
printer1    01.10.2022 12:32    12273   7826    4447
printer1    02.10.2022 12:32    12274   7826    4448
printer1    08.10.2022 12:32    12275   7826    4449
printer1    15.10.2022 12:32    12276   7826    4450
printer1    31.10.2022 12:32    12278   7826    4452
```

In this example, the pagecount for printer1 in mono would be 0 and for color 5 (calculation is done in PowerQuery)

If the values in table rows incrementing like this, the result of the calculation is correct.

```
Printer Quartal Year    first   last    first_Mono  last_Mono   first_Color last_Color
printer1    4   2022    12273   12278   7826    7826    4447    4452
```

Now sometimes the records showing an incorrect value (value is -1, instead):

```
printer1    20.10.2022 12:32    12276   -1  4450
```

In this case the result of pagecount for printer1 mono would be 7827 what is wrong.

```
Printer Quartal Year    first   last    first_Mono  last_Mono   first_Color last_Color
printer1    4   2022    12273   12278   -1  7826    4447    4452
```

The reason for the -1 value is related how the pagecount is retrieved from the printer and unfortunately this cannot be fixed.

I need some help to modify the query finding the first (MIN) and last (MAX) records (mono, color, all) related to the beginning and end of the interval (quarterly) where the value is not -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `having` clause:

```
...
GROUP BY 
    g_groupName
    , p_printerName
    , DATEPART(yy, pmh_pollDate)
    , DATEPART(q, pmh_pollDate)
HAVING
    (MIN(pmh_pageCountMono) <> -1) 
    AND (MAX(pmh_pageCountColor <> -1))
```

To get the NEXT min value you can do that:

1. Make query in a temporary table (#tmp) without any grouping, just to get all the rows.
2. Delete from temporary table (#tmp) records with -1 on columns of interest.
3. Rerun the query with "group by" over the temporary table #tmp.

Comment: I tried this: `HAVING MIN(pmh_pageCount) <> -1 
AND MAX(pmh_pageCount) <> -1`  - but this removes the whole record if there is a match inside the interval. If there is a -1 in any of the records (mono, color, all) inside the interval, the query should return the next "closest" one.

Comment: Than you should: 
1. Made a temporary table without grouping.
2. Delete from temporary table records with -1 
3. Rerun the querry with group by over the temporary table.

Comment: Finally I did the whole thing slightly different, however your input helped me finding a solution. Thx.